# Is it possible to make 3D games in Adobe Flash CS6 and ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: flash, 3d, adobe, game-engine, 3dsmax

I want to know whether I can make models in external software like 3DS Max and then import and use them in flash.

I want to make a game where there is a 3D animation of a an athlete running on athletic field.
How can I go about making that animation and using that in my flash game.

I think it must be possible as there are games like http://www.agame.com/game/street-sesh.html
which use 3d graphics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As JLeslie mentions, the example you're looking at is Shockwave (exported from Director) which has hardware acceleration support. Recently Flash Player 11 also added hardware acceleration so you can get similar quality graphics. I recommend using a modern actionscript 3D API like [Away3D](http://away3d.com) (which is free/opensource and supports various 3D formats that can be exported from 3dsmax) or [Flare3D](http://www.flare3d.com/) if you prefer to use GUIs more and code less (but have to pay for it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to bring models into flash and use them in the capacity you are talking about.  You CAN, however render out a series of images from 3DS Max and bring them into flash.

Other options are with applications like Papervision 3d which simulate a 3D environment.

EDIT:  The game you linked is run in Shockwave player not Flash which means it was most likely made in something like Adobe Director.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think Adobe Director is too hard to switch to if you know some adobe Flash? Is it too complicated?

Comment: That really all depends on what you feel your limitations are.  Director is different from flash in many ways, and yes it is more complicated.  Before switching I would look into using things like Papervision 3d which is essentially a "3D engine" for flash.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will have a look at papervision 3d! And since you are being so helpful, I had a look at your website :)

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer is **not correct** - since Flash player 11 we've had access to the Stage3D APIs, which allow hardware-accelerated 3d graphics within Flash Player. George Profenza's comment on your question points you in the right direction (I swear by Away3D!), not used Flare3D but it really depends on what you want - Director is also VERY far behind Flash in terms of language maturity, APIs, and developer/community support. By all means check it out, but I wouldn't choose it over Flash without a lot of good reasons!